# In Postgresql is it possible to do a "soft" commit of a transaction so far while retaining a row lock?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, transactions, knex.js

When using a transaction and a `select * ... FOR UPDATE` to lock a row, is it possible to do a "soft" commit that would write the changes so far to the table so they become permanent, *while* retaining the lock on the row?

In this specific use case, I have a long running function that triggers a series of operations based on a particular record. During that long running function, the row should remain locked for modification by other parts of the application.

However at different stages of the function there are side effect triggers that need to be be committed to the database (and made permanent).

If anything happens past one of those steps it would only roll back to that point.

If I just `COMMIT` then my current transaction finishes (and can't run further operations with that transaction) and any other queued operation kicks in.

`COMMIT AND CHAIN` doesn't prevent existing pending transactions from kicking in first.

Is there a way to do this at the database level?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. If you need to prevent concurrent data modifications for a longer time, long transactions are not a good solution. You should solve this with application logic, for example by adding a `boolean` column that indicates that the row is being worked on.